# Accepted Answer - Scored net 0 reputation

Tags: bug, reputation

I recently answered this question [Simulink For Iterator iteration limit visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328786/simulink-for-iterator-iteration-limit-visibility/66370952)

When I look in my profile, I can see that it shows as an accepted answer but when I look at the reputation tab for today's points, it shows that I was lost 15 points for the answer being unaccepted and gained 15 points for the answer being accepted scoring a net total of zero points.

[image]

What's going on? I have seen other answers to similar questions that suggest if the total daily points are over 200 things like this might happen but I'm only on 25 for today (should be 15 higher)

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead? Everything looks reasonable. Accepts and unaccepts do not interfere with daily reputation caps. Do you expect the unaccept to _not_ cause −15 reputation because it’s the _first_ thing that happened today? Why?

Comment: to second Sebastian's comment, also unsure what you expected to happen here. Unaccept deduces 15 points, subsequent accept adds them back, resulting in 0 net change for the day. You then had a post upvoted and accepted, resulting in +25 net change. So... where's the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

You got +15 when they accepted your answer on 2nd March. Then lost it and regained it today when they unaccepted and accepted the answer again. So, overall, you didn't lose anything. Not a bug.

Comment: In fact, there is a net gain of +15 for the Answer overall.